# Selecting Distance Between only two nodes in Apache Spark Graphs

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I want to calculate the shortest Distance Among Source and destination node using Scala and GraphX . But Following code gives me the Shortest distance among all nodes.

```
val sourceId: VertexId = 37 
val g = graph.mapVertices( (id, _) =>
                if (id == sourceId) 0.0
                else Double.PositiveInfinity
             )
val sssp = g.pregel(Double.PositiveInfinity)(
               (id, dist, newDist) => math.min(dist, newDist),
               triplet => {
                 if (triplet.srcAttr + triplet.attr < triplet.dstAttr) {
                   Iterator((triplet.dstId, triplet.srcAttr + triplet.attr))
                 }
                 else {
                   Iterator.empty
               }
                },
               (a, b) => math.min(a, b)
                )
```

OutPut:

```
(Dest Node,shortest Distance )
(18,991.6112077930221)
(38,379.8315724661152)
(14,1442.036238189988)
(22,1494.3250833673349)
(30,451.119421079875)
(10,1525.2322402611999)
(56,2313.01408644027)
(20,970.9823341266101)
```

For example: I want to calculate the distance between Source node:37 to Destination node:18, not among all nodes.
Can you please Guide me how I can specify the destination node in this code, so that I can find the just distance between source and destination, Not among All nodes.

Answer (score 2):

What about filtering the output, and leaving only the node that you're interested in? In your case this would be:

```
sssp.vertices.filter { case (destId, _) =>
  destId == 18
}
```

which would leave `(18,991.6112077930221)` in the output.

Comment: You can invoke `collect()` method on that RDD. So it would be something like: `sssp.vertices.filter(...).collect() foreach println`

Comment: I have implemented the above code using filtration it is working fine for small no  of nodes and edges. But I have encountered a problem while processing large (50k +) edges and nodes. The time taken for the operation exceeds more than a day. Is there any other way to modify above code just for source and destination nodes only without filtering the output.